# How to use custom makefile in DevC++ to call different makefiles in sub directories?Call leads to infinite loop without executing sub directory mkfile

Tags: makefile, nested

In UNIX the following code works fine with sub directories call, In DevC++ without these sub directories calling this makefile is running fine. I mean to say no problem in setting up the custom make file but calling is.

source code in make file:

```
$(IDMSOBJDIR)/idmslex.o :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/msgMgr.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h $(IDMSDIR)/idmskwords.rwd $(IDMSDIR)/idmslex.l
            cd $(IDMSDIR);  make

$(IDMSOBJDIR)/idmspar.o :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/msgMgr.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h $(IDMSDIR)/idmskwords.rwd $(IDMSDIR)/idmspar.y
            cd $(IDMSDIR);  make

$(CICSOBJDIR)/cicslex.o :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/msgMgr.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h $(CICSDIR)/cicskwords.rwd $(CICSDIR)/cicslex.l
            cd $(CICSDIR);  make

$(CICSOBJDIR)/cicspar.o :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/msgMgr.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h $(CICSDIR)/cicskwords.rwd $(CICSDIR)/cicspar.y
            cd $(CICSDIR)   
            make

$(CICSOBJDIR)/cicsunp.o :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/msgMgr.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h
            cd $(CICSDIR);  make

$(CICSOBJDIR)/cicskwordshash.o  :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h $(CICSDIR)/cicskwords.rwd
            cd $(CICSDIR);  make

$(DB2OBJDIR)/sqllex.o   :   $(INCLPATH)/rtbtree.h $(INCLPATH)/memmgmt.h $(INCLPATH)/rtbyacc.h $(INCLPATH)/msgMgr.h $(INCLPATH)/front.h $(INCLPATH)/setops.h $(INCLPATH)/nodedecl.h $(INCLPATH)/operators.h $(INCLPATH)/tokdefs.h $(DB2DIR)/sqlkwords.rwd $(DB2DIR)/sqllex.l
            cd ../db2/src;  make
```

Console of Dev C++:

```
make[205]: Entering directory 
cd ../cics/src                

make                          

make[206]: Entering directory 
cd ../cics/src                

make                          

make[207]: Entering directory 
cd ../cics/src                

make                          

make[208]: Entering directory 
cd ../cics/src                

.
.
.
```

It goes on , neither the control comes back nor it doesn't execute the make in the sub directory . I keeps on printing this line .

Comment: The recipe that has the `cd` and `make` split onto two lines is incorrect. Each line is its own shell session. So that recipe is running `make` in the current directory repeatedly. You also have duplicate recipes for generating different files. That's not going to do what you want exactly. That's going to run the recipe once per-file (if make is set up properly the second, etc. runs won't do much but it is still inefficient).

Comment: @EtanReisner  Could you suggest a way that it can implement perfectly. I couldn't comprehend the solution from the way you explains it.

Comment: Most of the pasted rules have `cd $(CICSDIR);  make`; that's a correct recipe line for that concept. One of the rules has `cd $(CICSDIR)` and `make` on separate lines; that's an incorrect recipe line for that idea. The `cd` affects a shell that is closed when the line ends and then `make` happens in its own shell. You need to combine those lines like the other rules. Additionally, you have the same `cd $(CICSDIR); make` recipe for every rule but expect them to generate different targets. That may work (if they generate all of them) but is going to make `make` run each rule independently.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for the answer, yeah that issue is resolved when i placed in the same line but still it is not working with the above mentioned command and if i put && in place of ; it works like a gem.

Comment: Does fixing that one rule fix your problem? Or does it just fix a problem and some other problem remains?